# How to install ElasticSearch on Windows?

Tags: windows, elasticsearch

I am new for elasticsearch.I searched in google about elasticsearch and how to install it.Is JDK is required for elasticsearch install and configure in windows OS.Please anyone suggest solution.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/windows.html

Comment: Have you tried this [Official Guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/windows.html) ?

Comment: yes i tried.But,i can't find elasticsearch.bat file

Comment: Extract the [zip](https://artifacts.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-5.4.1.zip) -> Under `bin` you will find the `elasticsearch.bat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you search in google for "elasticsearch install windows" you can find this link

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/windows.html

Which shows you note "Elasticsearch requires Java 8 or later. Use the official Oracle distribution or an open-source distribution such as OpenJDK."

Comment: yes i tried.But,i can't find elasticsearch.bat file in downloaded source

Comment: @Gopal where are you looking ?

Comment: @Gopal when you unzip folder go to root thre should be bin folder

Comment: yes got it. excute the command line queries. Getting "The syntax of the command is incorrect" error when excute ".\bin\elasticsearch.bat" query

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146591/discussion-between-volodymyr-bilyachat-and-gopal).

Comment: The link now goes to a 404 page

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Elasticsearch have an MSI package with a GUI installer. That's the easiest way to install.

If you prefer a manual install, you'll need to:

- get the ZIP file
- download and install Java, then set JAVA_HOME under System Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables
- finally, you can start Elasticsearch (via `elasticsearch.bat`) or install it as a service via `elasticsearch-service.bat install`